# Disable personal language library feature of Swype

Tags: swype

I dislike the way keyboards build a personal language library. I currently use Huawei Swype and whilst yes, every now and then I can clear the library, I would like to not have to do that.

Is there any way to disable this feature on Swype?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en) application? It pretty much allows you to [disable personalized corrections](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6102154?hl=en) and a few more options.

Comment: @benjaminS I did actually check it out because it comes pre-loaded on my phone as an alternative. I apparently overlooked the setting that was necessary! Make it an answer and take the points, it isn't the prettiest of keyboards but it does what I wanted where Swype seemed to refuse to

Comment: I just want you you to note that a part of the question is off-topic here (e.g. *Is there an app that does X?* ). Visit [help/on-topic] to know what's on-topic here *[et al](http://android.stackexchange.com/help)*.

Comment: @Firelord thanks for pointing it out, I admit I did not visit the android stack's help centre, probably should have done that before posting the question. Thanks for the guidance

Comment: I removed the bit about asking for recommendations. This question is fine as it is, currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [**Google Keyboard**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en) application? 
It pretty much allows you to [**disable personalized corrections**](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6102154?hl=en) and a few more options.

You have the option to change the following settings:

- Block offensive words: Block Google Keyboard from suggesting
  potentially offensive words.
- Auto-correction: Set the spacebar and any inserted punctuation to
  automatically correct mistyped words.
- Show correction suggestions: Show suggested words while typing.
- Personalized corrections: Set Google Keyboard to learn from your
  typing to improve its suggestions to you.
- Suggest Contact names: Use names from your contacts for suggestions
  and corrections.
- Next-word suggestions: Use the previous word in making suggestions.

source: [Google Support Page](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6102154?hl=en)